# upload file to dropbox using its link

Tags: javascript, node.js, dropbox-api

i would like to know if it is possible to upload file to dropbox using its link only and without downloading the file to the server.using nodejs in the server side or javascript in client side.the methode i am using now oblige me to download the file and then buffer it in order to send it after.

```
eq = http.get('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js', function(res) {
    var chunks = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('telechargement');
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on('end', function() {

        client.put('adaptation/jsfile.js', jsfile, function(status, reply) {
            console.log(reply);

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no method in the Core API to allow saving a file to Dropbox just via a URL.

But there is an interactive way for users to do this via the Saver: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver. Perhaps that meets your needs.

Comment: i was loking for a way that doesnt involve the saver .in other word storing the file without redirection or popup.

Comment: Understood. There's no API for that.